# Elastic search 7.14 with Centos 7 in Linode Server

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7, linode

I have installed Elastic search7.14 with the help of this [article](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360055446413-How-To-Install-Run-Elasticsearch?source=answerbot&auth_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjo5Mjc3OTc5LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNTE5ODM0NDExNDIyLCJ0aWNrZXRfaWQiOjk0NDUxNjg0LCJkZWZsZWN0aW9uX2lkIjo2NDQ5MTU4MDYzNjM5LCJhcnRpY2xlcyI6WzM2MDA1NTQ0NjQxMywzNjAwNTY2MTY1MTQsMzYwMDU4NTM5NzM0XSwidG9rZW4iOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MTY1NjYwOTg0N30.6eWM4PdGVyfLBkCAqbkQke_381toQNu_iwbLad6pfo8)

The elasticsearch.yml file is below. What I believe the problem is in the configuration. I want to use elastic search with magento 2.4.3 and the recomended versioun for magento 2.4.3 is Elasticsearch 7.10
My server is linode with centos 7 and 4core cpu and 8gb of ram. I have also changed the /jvm.options with Xms and Xmx with 1024mb

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
# cluster.name: myCluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
# node.name: My First Node
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#node.data : true
#node.roles: [ master ]
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: localhost
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
 http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
 discover.seed_hosts: []

#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#cluster.initial_master_nodes : []

#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true 



 But I'm unable to start my service it says

    elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-06-02 21:58:16 IST; 6s ago
         Docs: https://www.elastic.co
      Process: 20876 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 20876 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Further debugging with journalctl -xe says

```
        -- Unit user-1001.slice has finished shutting down.
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com dovecot[13248]: lmtp(21106): Connect from local
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com dovecot[13248]: lmtp(21106): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=GREETING)
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com dovecot[13248]: imap-login: Login: user=<__cpanel__service__auth__imap__q6pfahcr7hjsl
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com dovecot[13248]: imap(__cpanel__service__auth__imap__q6pfahcr7hjslimd)<21120><uNTkgHng
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com pure-ftpd[21128]: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] New connection from 127.0.0.1
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com pure-ftpd[21128]: (?@127.0.0.1) [INFO] __cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__tUDT5E9wzfQWUKh
        Jun 02 21:59:01 li2147-225.members.linode.com pure-ftpd[21128]: (__cpanel__service__auth__ftpd__tUDT5E9wzfQWUKhS@127.0.0.1) [INFO] 
        Jun 02 21:59:11 li2147-225.members.linode.com sshd[21168]: Invalid user mama from 165.232.141.0 port 60618
        Jun 02 21:59:11 li2147-225.members.linode.com sshd[21168]: input_userauth_request: invalid user mama [preauth]
        Jun 02 21:59:12 li2147-225.members.linode.com sshd[21168]: Received disconnect from 165.232.141.0 port 60618:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
        Jun 02 21:59:12 li2147-225.members.linode.com sshd[21168]: Disconnected from 165.232.141.0 port 60618 [preauth]
```

If you want to check the logs then, the last a few lines of this is like

```
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
            at org.elasticsearch.systemd.Libsystemd.lambda$static$0(Libsystemd.java:23) ~[?:?]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[?:?]
            at org.elasticsearch.systemd.Libsystemd.<clinit>(Libsystemd.java:22) ~[?:?]
            at org.elasticsearch.systemd.SystemdPlugin.sd_notify(SystemdPlugin.java:115) ~[?:?]
            at org.elasticsearch.systemd.SystemdPlugin.onNodeStarted(SystemdPlugin.java:126) ~[?:?]
            at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
            at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:971) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:313) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
            at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.1.jar:7.14.1]
```

Please give some advice, on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: we'd need to see more of your log please

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for the reply. Please check the below links. For Log link is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_-9pMQ2Yg--C1qzGOVE-qN7tTrQkm6F7NolVzYlJ8ls/edit?usp=sharing     And the Elasticsearch Configuration link is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ONdnyq-48G0MOoC60QPMAMJrTLNAWCm2qRaMjRpwO0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: did you install Elasticsearch 7.14 to start, and then install 7.10?